# How to handle Angular ng-click in Selenium/C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium

```
<div data-ng-if="showWorking==1 && editMode==0 && RecordsCountInWorking !=0" class="btn-group pull-right margin-left-20">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-ng-click="PromoteToFrozen()"  autofocus=""  title="Promote">Promote</button>
</div>

<div data-ng-if="showWorking==1 && editMode==1" class="btn-group pull-right margin-left-20">
    <button class="btn" data-ng-class="{'btn-default': (showWorking==1 && editMode==1) , 'btn-primary': !(showWorking==1 && editMode==1)}" type="button" data-ng-click="Save()">Save</button>
</div>



$scope.showWorking = 1;
$scope.editMode = 0;

$scope.markAsChanged = function (index) {    
    if (listOfChangedRows.indexOf(index) == -1) {    
        $scope.editMode = 1    
        listOfChangedRows.push(index);    
    }    
}
```

Here scenerio is if I change anything in the input box promote button triggered to save button so if i take xpath for save button, no such element method error is coming please give me any suggestion to do that?

Comment: DON'T USE CAPS LOCK!!!

Comment: And post your code.

Comment: <div data-ng-if="showWorking==1 && editMode==0 && RecordsCountInWorking !=0" class="btn-group pull-right margin-left-20">

        

            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-ng-click="PromoteToFrozen()"  autofocus=""  title="Promote">Promote</button>

        </div>

 

        <div data-ng-if="showWorking==1 && editMode==1" class="btn-group pull-right margin-left-20">

 

           promote button dom

Comment: Just to understand clearly, you are changing some value in the input box and as soon as you change, the 'Promote' button gets hidden and 'Save' button gets visible? and you want to click on Save button?